# Can I use bitcoin USB block erupters to mine litecoin?

Tags: litecoin, block, hash

Let's say I buy a USB block erupter, can I use the same to mine Litecoins?

Does it require special software and setup to mine Litecoins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. USB block erupters are ASIC miners. They cannot have their algorithm modified in any way because the algorithm is designed into the silicon. They can only mine coins that use the same mining algorithm as Bitcoin (SHA256d) such as Namecoin and Devcoin.

Comment: Just to add to this, Litecoins were designed so that they would not work with ASIC miners.  This way, mining would be limited to CPU/GPU computations rather than buying cheaper ASIC miners and diluting the supply of LTC.